# How to find the intent name to start App Power Saving Mode settings activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, samsung-mobile, power-saving

I have an Android alarm clock app.  It is allowed to ring in Doze mode and is not effected by Android App Optimization because it uses AlarmManager.setAlarmClock().  It is rock solid reliable EXCEPT for Samsung phones - they have App Power Saving mode that does NOT care if AlarmManager.setAlarmClock() is used - if it is not exempt, it does not ring.  I need to have the users exempt my app, but it is too complicated to ask the user to navigate to the settings activity for App Power Saving Mode.  If I had the APK for Samsung settings, I could probably look in the manifest to find the intent to launch, but I don't.  Does anyone know how to get the intent name that is required to launch the Samsung App Power Saving mode settings?

Comment: Install [Applications Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majeur.applicationsinfo) and take a look at the Settings app's manifest, to see if anything seems likely. Bear in mind that the activity may not be exported and may vary by Samsung device.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am having this same problem.